# Adding a third-party control to my custom Word Ribbon Tab

Tags: xml, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, ribbon

I have a custom ribbon tab, created through a Word Add-In. I would like to add some controls from a third-party (not Microsoft) ribbon. I believe that using the "idQ" attribute is the way forward, but no matter what I do, it does not work.

I have tried setting up my own "mock third-party" add-in, so that I have control of both ribbon tabs, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Only standard controls are supported in the office ribbon. You can't put any third-party controls there. idQ is for creating unique name for sharing controls between different addins.